# Ubuntu slow booting - 'sendmail.service' takes over a minute to load

Tags: boot, performance, services, sendmail

My ubuntu is booting very slowly. I'll show here excerpts from `dmesg` where the difference in boot time is larger than one second.

Which one of these entries is significant, and which is not? (In terms of the norm. I can see myself that the last entries have the largest time-difference, but it's not clear to the untrained eye whether that's within normal tolerances or not). And what can I do about them?

```
[    3.339708] systemd[1]: RTC configured in localtime, applying delta of 120 minutes to system time.
[    4.001290] systemd[1]: systemd 229 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN)
[    4.018390] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <foo-bar>.
[    6.087475] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[   11.484565] Adding 16646140k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16646140k FS
[   13.358114] audit: type=1400 audit(1466263617.866:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/ubuntu-core-launcher" pid=630 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.644036] audit: type=1400 audit(1466263618.150:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=627 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.866759] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
[   19.540776] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   19.540829] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 847 at /build/linux-oXTOqc/linux-4.4.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:1144 intel_disable_pipe+0x2b6/0x2c0 [i915]()
[   19.784310] [drm:drm_edid_block_valid [drm]] *ERROR* EDID checksum is invalid, remainder is 140
[   26.762481] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   27.020066] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   28.554052] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[   28.554057] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[   28.554090] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  290.868877] show_signal_msg: 48 callbacks suppressed
[  290.868883] cal-client-dbus[3618]: segfault at 4330443618 ip 00007f0886c485a9 sp 00007f0855ffa350 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f0886bca000+1c0000]
[  644.443348] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder B
[  644.443375] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder B FIFO underrun
[  831.364787] gvfsd-dnssd[9183]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fb336559b5a sp 00007fff12abefd8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7fb3364bb000+1c0000]
[  831.546627] gvfsd-dnssd[9181]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f59f4fd3b5a sp 00007ffcfd0ed1b8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f59f4f35000+1c0000]
```

My version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

The output of `systemd-analyze blame`

```
     1min 2.716s sendmail.service
         15.367s teamviewerd.sysv.service
          9.686s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          9.153s lightdm.service
          7.907s ModemManager.service
          6.312s squid.service
          5.912s NetworkManager.service
          5.891s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          5.492s apparmor.service
          5.353s dev-sda5.device
          5.090s accounts-daemon.service
          4.280s gpu-manager.service
          3.236s console-kit-log-system-start.service
          3.185s systemd-logind.service
          3.148s pppd-dns.service
          3.148s selfcontrol.service
          3.092s irqbalance.service
          3.069s grub-common.service
          2.940s speech-dispatcher.service
          2.260s rsyslog.service
          1.722s plymouth-start.service
          1.695s avahi-daemon.service
          1.265s apt-daily.service
          1.162s polkitd.service
          1.128s ondemand.service
           975ms systemd-journald.service
           945ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
           888ms systemd-udevd.service
           872ms colord.service
           765ms thermald.service
           696ms apport.service
           672ms systemd-modules-load.service
           642ms ssh.service
           633ms networking.service
           588ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           588ms ufw.service
           587ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           586ms dev-mqueue.mount
           586ms dev-hugepages.mount
           556ms upower.service
           498ms systemd-user-sessions.service
           495ms console-kit-daemon.service
           440ms udisks2.service
           427ms console-setup.service
           330ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           314ms dns-clean.service
           247ms systemd-random-seed.service
           226ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
           212ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           154ms systemd-sysctl.service
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you using? Please add that to your question. Also try to run `systemd-analyze blame` and add the output (probably works only on 15.04 or 15.10 and newer...).

Comment: @ByteCommander Is this all you wanted?

Comment: Yes, thanks. As you see, the `sendmail.service` takes most time to boot, about one minute. `teamviewerd.sysv.service` is also slowing it down notably with about 15 seconds running time. I don't really know how to investigate further on this, but it seems to be mainly caused by those two network related services.

Comment: Have you checked sendmail log files? ( /var/log/mail* on Debian)

Comment: Have you tried changing line 23 of */etc/profile* to `( . $i) &` (without the parenthesis -- this forum does not highlight the code correctly without the parenthesis)?